# How can we Get Focus window using c/c++ in MACOS

Tags: c++, c, macos

I am trying to write a program whose requirement is to get the focused window title name, I have used "CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo" API which results in all active window list and I want currently focused window title only.

Language -C/C++
Platform - MacOs

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: @chaitan64arun I am trying to get the only name of current focused window and in the given link it gives a list of the active window